# What is the Python translation of ReDim in VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a VBA script which I want to translate to Python. I have some really basic VBA knowledge (wrote two small Excel macro's, 1,5 year ago). However the Python script still doesn't deliver the right results and I think it is caused by two "ReDim lines". These lines looks as follows:

```
ReDim TmpDividendTimes(1 To NoOfDividends) As Variant
ReDim TmpCashDividends(1 To NoOfDividends) As Variant
```

My question is, what is the function of these two lines? And how can those be translated to Python? The whole relevant VBA code looks as follows:

```
Function BinomialDD(Variable_X As String(), Variable_Y As String(),_
                    Optional CashDividends As Variant, Optional DividendTimes As Variant)

Dim TmpDividendTimes() As Variant
Dim TmpCashDividends() as Variant
Dim NoOfDividends As Integer

If IsMissing(DividendTimes) Or IsEmpty(DividendTimes Then
    NoOfDividends=0
Else
    NoOfDividends=Application.Count(DividentTimes)
End If

If NoOfDividends=0 Then
    //Non-Relevant
   Exit Function
End If

ReDim TmpDividendTimes(1 To NoOfDividends) As Variant
ReDim TmpCashDividends(1 To NoOfDividends) As Variant
```

I already tried (guessed) the following solution in Python:

```
TmpDividendTimes=CashDividends
TmpCashDividends=DividendTimes
```

```
TmpDividendTimes=np.arange(0,NoOfDividends+1,1)
TmpCashDividends=np.arange(0,NoOfDividends+1,1)
```

Because what I understand from examples on the internet that you create a new variable.

Comment: My understanding is that `Redim` is used to dynamically size the array at runtime (when you don't know in advance/during declaration what size the array needs to be). I think the concept of `Redim` doesn't really translate to Python, as Python `lists` (which roughly translate to VBA `arrays`) are more flexible and you can simply call `List.Append` method to add something to a list, without needing to handle dimension/capacity details yourself.

Comment: As I know `Dim` is used to declare variable before you use it. But in Python you don't have to declare before you use. And you can't even declare without assigning value - so lines with `Dim` can be useless in Python. `ReDim` will means redeclaration of variable - assign new definition to variable. It also can be useless in Python. I'm not sure for `Variant` - it can means some some list or table and it can be in pyton `TmpDividendTimes = []` but for list you don't have to declare size like in `(1 To NoOfDividends) As Variant` because you can use `append()` to resize when you need it.

Comment: @chillin I Understand, the ReDim statement is not that relevant for the Python script. I will look further into it, thanks all ready!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, what is the function of these two lines?

These statements declare [dynamic arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays):

```
Dim TmpDividendTimes() As Variant
Dim TmpCashDividends() as Variant
```

These statements change the size of of those arrays - They ["...reallocate storage space ..."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement):

```
ReDim TmpDividendTimes(1 To NoOfDividends) As Variant
ReDim TmpCashDividends(1 To NoOfDividends) As Variant
```

`ReDim` will *destroy* any previous contents.

---

> And how can those be translated to Python?

Python's [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) and [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) could be considered analogous to VB's array but neither require a `ReDim` statement to change their size - their *size* is not fixed. There are other Python containers that could be used depending on what you need the container to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It has become clear to me.